# How to return the value (title, public date, link) from XML then store it into the List?

Tags: python, xml, list, elementtree

I'm working with PYTHON class and The ElementTree XML

Here is my code so far of the class:

```
class Story():
def __init__(self, title, link, pub_date):
    # TODO: your code here
    self.title = title
    self.link = link
    self.pub_date = pub_date
def __str__(self):
    # TODO: your code here
    return self.title + '. (' + self.pub_date + ')' + '\n' + self.link
```

The code of Parsing XML:

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss'

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
   data = response.read()
   root = ET.fromstring(data)
   channel = root[0]
   for news_title in channel.iter('title'):
       print(news_title.text + '\n')
   for news_pub_date in channel.iter('pubDate'):
       print(news_pub_date.text + '\n')
   for news_link in channel.iter('link'):
       print(news_link.text + '\n')
```

I can print the title, public date, and the link but they are separate.
So, how can I combine with the class to store the contents in the list to print the result like this:

The White House has 132 rooms and its own restaurant. Here's what it's like inside Joe Biden's new home.(2021-02-25T20:21:03Z)
https://news.yahoo.com/us-bombs-facilities-syria-used-003717572.html

Why is the Texas snowstorm attracting anti-Biden conspiracy theories? (2021-02-26T00:37:17Z)
https://news.yahoo.com/sturgeon-blasts-salmond-faces-claim-193113374.html

The requirement of this question is I need to create a def to get the contents and return it in the list:

```
def get_contents(source='yahoo') -> List[content]:
     contents = []

     # Do some code here

     return contents
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where is the xml example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a much more efficient list comprehension specific to the XML you provided:

```
contents = [[ch[0].text,ch[1].text, ch[2].text] for ch in channel[8:]]
```

this accomplishes the same as the code below but without the need to iterate over each title, pubDate, or link.

This appears to be a workable solution using list comprehension(old):

```
    titles = [nt.text for nt  in channel.iter('title')]
    dates = [pd.text for pd  in channel.iter('pubDate')]
    links = [nl.text for nl  in channel.iter('link')]
    contents = [[titles[i], dates[i], links[i]] for i in range(len(titles)-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) to get all `item` elements and then use [`find()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) to get `title`, `link` and `pubDate` child from each `item`, for example:

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss'
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
    data = response.read()
    root = ET.fromstring(data)
    for item in root.findall('channel/item'):
        print(item.find('title').text)
        print(item.find('link').text)
        print(item.find('pubDate').text)
        print()
```